# (Jade) a href that has its link as the displayed text

Tags: href, pug

The relevant line in my code is: `a(href = data[i][propt] ) data[i][propt]`. data[i][propt] stores the URL, for instance, www.google.com. However, this way, what is shown on the webpage is a clickable `data[i][propt]` that directs to www.google.com. But what I wanted is a clickable `www.google.com` that directs to www.google.com. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
a(href = data[i][propt]) #{data[i][propt]}
```

or:

```
a(href = data[i][propt])= data[i][propt]
```